# how to make a mesh material change color depending on position of an empty

Tags: mesh, materials

I'd like a mesh representing a muscle change color (say, from white to red) when the muscle is contracted. I hooked the mesh to the bone it controls (an element of exoskeleton actually, since I'm modeling an insect). The effected bone can move in all directions, but the muscle contracts only along the Y axis. I'd like to be able to feed the Y position of either the empty I used as the hook, or a nearby vertex group of the muscle mesh itself, to, say, a mix shader fac input.
Any ideas how to accomplish that? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This will depend on your rig, I guess, but you could use a driver.

To keep it simple, you could:

- Drive a 'Value' Input Node
- Parent a relatively-moving Empty (E1) at one end of the muscle to a root Empty (E0) at the other end. You may already have components that are effectively parented this way in your rig.
- In this case, E1 is constrained to move only in its parent's local Y
- It has a (Local Space) Limit Location constraint along that axis to stop it going out of range.. your rig may be doing this another way.

The driver can then be created by (right-click) 'Copy as New Driver' in E1's Y location field in the 'N' panel, and 'Paste Driver' in the Value node. The Y location will be in E0's space.

[image]

As above, you can map E1's [Min Y > Max Y] to 0-1, so it fits a color-ramp.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way you to do this is with a *Texture Coordinate Node* where you have set the *Object*  to your empty, similar to this trivial example:

[image: Using a texture coordinate node for empty coordinates]

I've hooked the output of the texture's *Object* coordinates to a *Separate XYZ* node.  For my example I used the X output, but the Y output will work for you.

The tricky bit is that the object coordinates are no longer clamped to -1 to 1 on each axis, so you have to do a bit of math to use them effectively, since you have to map those coordinates to the 0 to 1 range expected by most nodes.  Rather, the Object coordinates are the distances to the origin of the empty, measured along its own local coordinate system

To make up for my earlier bad explanation, here's a shader that controls the colors of a cube by using all three axis of an empty.  Note that the cube's color varies across the cube because it's the distance from the given point on the cube to the origin of the empty that matters.

The mapping nodes mean that the empty can move +/- 5 units along any axis to achieve the full effect, with negative distances being darker and positive lighter.

[image: 3d control of cube color by empty]

Comment: I think I see what you mean, but the Object texture coordinates are measured in the Object Space of the referenced object, or the shaded object ('self') if there's no reference.  A subtraction of the spaces will be constant throughout the shaded object  _if_ they are aligned in Y and the objects are at the same scale. .. ?

Comment: Thank you, it's working with 2 texture coordinate nodes and a "less than" math node pretty well, although the change is a bit abrupt, I might try smoothing it out with more math. Or a color ramp node somewhere down the line :)

Comment: You guys don't disappoint, thank you so much!

Comment: @RobinBetts  IIRC, if the Object input field is used, Object output has a different meaning than if the texture coordinate is from the current object.  In this case, the Object output is in world coordinates.

Comment: @Marty YDNRC... https://imgur.com/a/wxKHgY0   :)

Comment: @RobinBetts  oops.  fixing answer now

Comment: +1 anyway, I prefer the idea of doing without a driver.. and @Igor says it works for him.

Comment: @RobinBetts I don't think that video shows what you think it shows but I've got to go do things.  I'll get back to you in a few hours

Comment: @Marty sure thing. The gif shows the XYZ of the Empty's object space, encoded as RGB, intersecting the surface of the shaded cube. We may just have crossed wires about the meanings of words. When I say 'Object Space' of object O, I mean the coordinate system whose `basis` (in the mathematical sense) is the object axes of O (which carry  O's transform). My 'World Space' is the coordinate system aligned  to the World,  scaled at 1, with its origin at World 0.

Comment: @RobinBetts It was mostly me being sloppy and wrong.  Your last comment is spot on.  The sneaky bit about using an object in the Object input of a Texture Coordinate node is not that it is in World Space, but that it's not clamped to -1,1 on any axis.  So my first method works because it is the delta between the origins of the empty and the other object, but as you point out in your answer, has issues with scaling.  I think your way works welll.